# WebBrowser dont show in tabitem

Tags: c#, wpf, chromium-embedded

I try to develop WebBrowser on c#, wpf and CefSharp for experience. 
I use TabControl for tabs in WebBrowser.
So i add webbrowser to tabItem.Content but it dont showing up.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ChromiumWebBrowser webBrowser;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        //Browser init
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        Cef.Initialize(settings);

        InitializeComponent();
        textboxURL.Text = "https://www.google.com";
        webBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
        webBrowser.Load(textboxURL.Text);
        tabItem1.Content = webBrowser;
    }

    //App Shutdown logic
    private void Exit(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Cef.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

This is XAML code. As you see i use DockPanel for topbar with URL and buttons.
And TabControl for tabs with browser. For now i use only one webBrowser for one tab.

```
Window x:Class="WebBrowser.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WebBrowser"
    xmlns:cefSharp="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="WebBrowser" Height="362" Width="699" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,-1" Height="auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
    <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Button x:Name="btnHome" Content="Home" Margin="2" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnBack" Content="Back" Margin="2" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnNext" Content="Next" Margin="2" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
        <Label x:Name="labelHttp" Content="HTTP" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnMenu" Content="Menu" Margin="2" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnGo" Content="Go" Margin="2" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnRefresh" Content="Refresh" Margin="2" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textboxURL" Margin="2"/>
    </DockPanel>
    <TabControl x:Name="tabControl1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,5,0,0" Height="299">
        <TabItem Header="TabPage" Name="tabItem1">
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: The size of webrowser may be larger than tab so you aren't seeing the control.  Also try bringing webbrowser to front and make sure it is enabled.

Comment: @jdweng if i add in XAML tabitem.Content <cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser/> all works. But i cant add by c# code.

Comment: Just add it as Content of TabItem, mark with Key and use it for Initialization.

Comment: @Shakra nope, i need to add webBrowser for another tabitems by c# code.

Comment: It's a bad way of using control at WPF, much better would be to use `Address` property of browser.

Comment: @shakra method Load specially for loading new page.

Comment: I know but it looks like you want to 'recreate' browser... and I want to help you solve a problem, if it works fine when  you define cefBrowser at xaml, define it there once, and when you need to place it into another tabs you can detach it from one tabitem and attach it to another one. But imho it far from mvvm.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i try to use Address property then init browser and its load my url!
So answer is dont use webBrowser.Load(textboxURL.Text); on new element but use webBrowser.Address = textBoxURL.Text;
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

### --With CefSharp you can with this code--

```
public ChromiumWebBrowser drv;
    string url = "https://www.example.com"; 
    public void syhmhfzaddtab()
    {
        TabPage tb = new TabPage();
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        Cef.Initialize(settings);

        drv = new ChromiumWebBrowser(url);
        drv.Parent = tb;
        tabControl1.Controls.Add(tb);
        drv = new ChromiumWebBrowser(url);
        drv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
```

Note:%100 a working code